# Client-Side Image Map in Elementor

Tags: image, dictionary, elementor

I am trying to implement a client-side image map on the home page of my client's site. I used the free generator and generated this code, however, the map links only to the first link (Western U.S. locations.) Here's the code:

```
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://crossdockameri.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/CD-BREAKOUTMAP.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="Western U.S. Cross Dock Locations" title="Western U.S. Cross Dock Locations" href="https://crossdockameri.wpengine.com/western-us-cross-dock-locations" coords="269,38,136,581,94,936,123,1371,240,1701,261,1893,733,1943,1226,2014,1343,1943,1627,1918,1664,1504,1756,1463,1765,1099,1635,1045,1689,280" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Midwest U.S. Cross Dock Locations" title="Midwest U.S. Cross Dock Locations" href="https://crossdockameri.wpengine.com/midwest-us-cross-dock-locations" coords="1877,150,1790,1095,1911,1153,1915,1496,1844,1517,1794,1968,1518,1968,1585,2106,1706,2286,1857,2315,1919,2269,2057,2457,2174,2624,2308,2645,2324,2486,2395,2390,2558,2294,2734,2277,2855,2315,3005,2319,2993,2169,2926,2064,2792,2077,2842,1914,2859,1759,2926,1609,3076,1550,3439,1504,3490,1404,3465,1320,3515,1229,3556,1095,3540,940,3377,786,3293,652,3226,539,2805,389,2826,163" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Northeast U.S. Cross Dock Locations" title="Northeast U.S. Cross Dock Locations" href="https://crossdockameri.wpengine.com/northeast-us-cross-dock-locations" coords="3565,338,3544,560,3911,568,3832,648,3753,773,3774,986,3665,1178,3761,1316,3895,1208,3970,1103,4120,1153,4187,1220,4283,1091,4292,944,4388,832,4467,752,4567,648,4505,589,4509,472,4663,309,4601,226,4505,54,4312,259" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Southeast U.S. Cross Dock Locations" title="Southeast U.S. Cross Dock Locations" href="https://crossdockameri.wpengine.com/southeast-us-cross-dock-locations" coords="3201,1663,3089,1910,3101,2064,3068,2194,3181,2223,3264,2307,3439,2290,3586,2298,3673,2328,3732,2273,3807,2374,3878,2532,3982,2662,4120,2704,4166,2566,4099,2407,4041,2294,4546,2257,4517,2018,4003,2023,4133,1864,4262,1738,4329,1575,4308,1417,4187,1300,4074,1245,3949,1341,3853,1492,3636,1567" shape="poly">
</map>
```

If you go to the page, the second appearance of the map is the one used with the above code. The first appearance is an attempt to implement it by setting up separate images and then absolute positioning the images and linking to those individuals images, which I don't really want to do.

Any help to implement the image map correctly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The image needed to be properly scaled and then the hotspots outlined on that scaled image. So there was nothing wrong with the html! Now on to figure out how to create an image map that is responsive.